# Using Re2 regex to pull content between 2 brackets in a specific location on the string

Tags: regex

I wondered if anyone could help me, I'm trying to pull the content after "en" and only between the following brackets /en/[here]/ so in the below example, it should return "about".

/content/web/gx/en/**about**/analyst-research/archive/market

All the URLs have the same pattern at the beginning (i.e. /content/web/gx/en), I'm actually using Google sheets for this, which uses Re2. I've tried various approaches, but I haven't used regex much, so struggling with this. Any help welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex :

```
en\/([^\/]*)\/
```

For `/content/web/gx/en/about/analyst-research/archive/market` it will return `about`.

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/vacPUu/2)

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern can be used to extract your text:

```
/content/web/gx/en/(\w+).*
```

See the full solution with capturing the group:
https://regex101.com/r/C9S7P4/2